# SwiftUI: Sort list based on an @Published variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-environment

I'm building a UI with SwiftUI, and I have an array that I use to build a `List` element. Now I want to sort that list based on a `@Published` variable coming from an `@EnvironmentObject`.

#### Approach 1

I tried getting the array already sorted, passing in the environment object to the sorting method:

```
List(getArraySorted(environmentObject)) { item in
    //do stuff with item
}
```

This will compile, but the list will not update if `environmentObject` changes. I also tried passing in `environmentObject.variableToBaseSortOn` but to no avail.

#### Approach 2

I tried sorting the array inline in Swift UI:

```
List(array.sorted(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    // do sorting based on self.environmentObject
})) { item in
    // do stuff with item
}
```

This will compile, but crash:

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type EnvironmentObjectClass found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for EnvironmentObjectClass may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

The hint in the crash is incorrect, `environmentObject` is set and `self.environmentObject` is set to the correct object.

Comment: is it possible you copy a reproducable example of your code here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your best approach is probably to sort the list within `ObservableObject` each time the data changes using a property observer, then manually informing the `ObservableObject` publisher of the change (rather than using `@Published`, so the unsorted array is not briefly published between changes.)

It's not a good idea to do the sorting directly in the `body` of the `View` because that block may be called many, many times as SwiftUI renders it (this is transparent to us as developers). I suspect that may be a reason that Approach 2 is not working.

For example:

```swift
import Combine

class SomeObject: ObservableObject {

    // or whatever data type you need...
    var array: [String] {
        didSet {
            array.sort(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
                // do sorting based on self.environmentObject
            })
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: creating a property that's "ready-to-use" by SwiftUI seems to indeed be the best way. In my case, I was able to create a new array with the sorted contents, publish it and update that.

Comment: Their ObservableObject is in the environment which likely means it is a model object, you wouldn’t want to be sorting that if a view isn’t onscreen that requires the data to be sorted. Sorting, formatting etc should be done in the View struct, or a @StateObject owned by the View if a reference type is needed for some other reason.